# Rxjs notify when all http requests finish with error handling for each request

Tags: typescript, rxjs, subscription, rxjs-observables

Hi I have some class objects to POST and I need to store the result back into them, e.g.:

```
class Bid {
    price: number;
    result?: string;
}
const bids: Bid[] = [{price: 10},{price:20}];
for (const bid of bids) {
    http.post(bid).subscribe(
        r => bid.result = r,
        e => bid.result = "error:" + e
    );
}
```

So far so good, but now I want to be notified when all POSTs return, as if I am forkjoining all the POSTs and subscribe to that, then do something when they all complete.

Different from forkjoin is I need to do error handling in each POST subscription.

I wonder how that can be done as I also need to subscribe to each POST to store the result in each corresponding source class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, a combination of

- `tap` to store the result in each object and manage errors for each post
- `catchError` to avoid error propagation
- `forkJoin` to glue the posts together

should work.

A solution could be along these lines

```
class Bid {
    price: number;
    result?: string;
}
const bids: Bid[] = [{price: 10},{price:20}];

const posts = bids.map(bid => {
   return http.post(bid).pipe(
     // taps accepts an Observer as parameter
     tap({
       next: res => bid.result = r,
       error: e => bid.result = "error:" + e
     }),
     // catch the error and return something that signals the error occurence
     catchError(err => of('Error'))
   )
})

forkJoin(posts).subscribe({
   next: data => {// data is an array containing either the result or the error }
   complete: () => console.log('I am Done')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems forkJoin does not work here if post() throws an error, then forkJoin never completes.

Comment: you are right, we need to add a `catchError` operator in the `pipe` - I update my response

Comment: Can confirm the update works! Thank you very much! Probably we can move the tap error part into the catchError as well.

Comment: I am not sure you can move the error part to `catchError` since you need a reference to `bid` which you have in `tap` but not in `catchError`. To be somehow poetic, we can remind that `tap` is there to manage side effects, and the fact that you want to change the state of `bid` setting some value in the `error` property is actually a side effect.